# uploading binary files in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Good morning, I have a problem related to how I process a form like this:

```html
<form action="/Resource/UpdateGallery"  method="post" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="idResource" />
</form>
```

Then Its sent using this plugin event:

```js
thisDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {}
```

Then this is the `Form Data` parsed:

```
idResource: 1
file: (binary)
```

and this is my controller, where I suppose to sent to an url this images:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateGallery(IFormFile file, int idResource)
        {
            //var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

            string urlGaleryResource = "http://urlurl/gallery/";
            var path = urlGaleryResource + idResource.ToString();
            string pathFinal = path + file.FileName;

            if(file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var FileStream = new FileStream(pathFinal, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(FileStream);
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

But It gives me this error:

```
IOException: The file name, or directory name or flag sintax are not correct :
C:\WorkingFolder\proyecto\proyecto\src\project\http:\urlurl\gallery\resources\1\4jpg'
```

Why Its adding the `C:\myfolderblabla\http:\...` when I suppose to get just this?:

> `http:\urlurl\gallery\1\4.jpg'`

Comment: You cannot give a Uri (http://...) to a FileStream like this, look at the path it complains about, this is an invalid path. Are you actually trying to upload the file via http or saving it to local disk?

Comment: Yes! Trying to upload the file via http!!

Comment: You cannot do that with a FileStream, you need to utilize HttpClient, WebClient or WebRequest or similar. And you also need to to figure out how to POST the filedata to the remote server so it saves it through some API or something similar.

Comment: Is the file you uploaded online or a file in your project folder? Is it a file under the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Thank you @TomasSchmidt, I'll take a look (:

Comment: Hi @Yongqing Yu, the target folder is on the Web una uri like this: `http://placeforphotos/gallery/etcetc`